# facing an issue bootstrap menu partition

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to set the menu and company name in one row. first I set the company name and after some spaces add a menu but the menu did not work in one row. last two hour trying and trying to face a bootstrap partition

**_CustomLayout.cshtml**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    @Styles.Render("~/template/css")
    <title>Abc - Free Responsive Template using Bootstrap 4</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .companyname {
            font-size: 22px;
            font-family: "Lato-Black";
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="companyname">asasdasdasd Technology</a>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Services", "Index", "Home")
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.ActionLink("AboutUs", "Index", "Home")
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Blog", "Index", "Home")
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Hire Developers", "Index", "Home")
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Career", "Index", "Home")
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Get a Quote", "Index", "Home")
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @RenderBody()
```

[image]

I want to set the company name after some spaces and then the menu in one row.

Comment: @admin it is possible ```<div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-4">```  then 12 partion of bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you most probably want this. you need to partition a row in two part

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="companyname">asasdasdasd Technology</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Services", "Index", "Home")
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.ActionLink("AboutUs", "Index", "Home")
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Blog", "Index", "Home")
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Hire Developers", "Index", "Home")
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Career", "Index", "Home")
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Get a Quote", "Index", "Home")
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: row and companyname in one row thanks but not satisfy the output https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOyU3.png

Comment: @AayushiBabariya you need to write CSS for that i just answered according to your  question